# Make editable EditText on LongClick in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to make EditText field in ListView editable on LongClick on item.
I've searched same topics on Stackoverflow, but haven't found best for my case.

Here is EditText from xml for ListView item:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/list_title_parent_item"
style="@style/list_parent_title_text"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:focusable="false"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:lines="1" />
```

Firstly it disabled from editing and shows only text. But by longclick on item, it must be editable. I've tried to did it by setting onitemlonglistener to listview:

```
private class ListViewOnLongClickListener implements OnItemLongClickListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
        GroupListAdapter adapter = (GroupListAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
        adapter.setTitleEditable();         
        return true;
    }
}

public void setTitleEditable() {
    holder.title.setEnabled(true);
    holder.title.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    Log.e("longclick", "!!!");
}
```

But without success - editText won't be editable after long click and also I can't make long click on editText area, but only on listview item.

Answer (score 1):

> But without success - editText won't be editable after long click and
>   also I can't make long click on editText area, but only on listview
>   item.

In the row XML layout, you should set all items except for the EditText to `focusable:false`. This will allow the EditText to receive the Long Press event.